# Difference between a IDE and text editor?

Tags: text, ide, editor

What's the true difference between an IDE and text editor with a bunch of plugins? Why should I prefer an IDE over a text editor for development?

Comment: If it natively (without plugins) compiles code, I'm inclined to say it's an IDE. Though I'm sure there are a fair amount of text editors that do this.

Comment: I disagree with those who vote for closing. It is about "software tools commonly used by programmers" and so explicitly [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @usr2564301 Every question about "software tools commonly used by programmers" isn't on topic. [Shark vs Gorilla questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/) generally aren't useful.

Comment: @RobertLongson: are you referring to the use of the word "prefer"? There is an *objective* difference between an IDE (generalized as this is, but applying a generous definition) and a plain text editor. There are *objective* (and good) reasons to use one over another, personal preferences aside.

Comment: @usr2564301 Depends what the plugins do. Their capability is undefined in the question. So we're supposed to compare undefined thing A with undefined thing B and reach a conclusion.

Comment: @RobertLongson: okay, I see. "If one can add all relevant plugins to a plain text editor, then how would this be any different from an IDE." With the opiniated ans.: "it would not be and so it comes down to whatever you prefer to use".

Comment: Indeed, we'd be back to Shark vs Gorilla.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

IDE stands for "Integrated development environment" not just a tool where you write the code, but you can also compile it and debug it.. 
text editors in their nature, usually don't do that, they tend to go for a broader approach..
be able to edit all types of files, instead of specializing in a particular type or language..

sure you can have plugins, specific for a type of file or language, that compiles/runs/debugs but since is it done by plugins, I guess the "integrated" part is off the table, so doesn't make much sense to call it IDE

And as said before, because the nature of the text editors the potential for integrated development experience will always be limited

Answer (score 6):

In the end, you want something that's going to make you the most productive. Whether that's Notepad or Vim or Sublime or something else is up to the user and the tasks required at the time.

With that said, an IDE does bring some solid benefits for development. Depending on the language and IDE, this may include integrated build tools, source control management, unit testing tools, automatic boilerplate generation, and class/variable refactoring.

Answer (score 6):

"IDE" isn't a very well defined term, but in my experience single unit IDEs (as opposed to editor + added plugins) seem to have more powerful debuggers, more integration between different tools in the IDE (e.g. easy to debug unit tests, use of deep code analysis to feed autocompletion, etc).  And of course more things work out of the box w/o having to download and configure plugins yourself, and the GUI is often are easier to figure out for new users or novices.  But it's a personal choice and the bottom line is you should try the tools you're considering and choose the one that fits best with your needs.

Answer (score -11):

IDE is stands for "Integrated Developement Environment" where the programmer can develop efficient projects and it provides drag and drop facility which reduces the stress of a programmer. Editor is one which is related to a specific language where you an write the program and run the program..

Comment: I have quite a few editors, and not one of them "is related to a specific language". otoh, some of my IDEs invoke different editors for every language.

Comment: why google is showing this as an answer when we search `difference between editor and ide`