# Getting started with VS code as C++ IDE

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio, ide

I want to use VS code as my C++ IDE. I installed it from the AUR(I'm using linux). But I got a bug. I tried to solve it following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-compile-c-code) topic. My json task is like the one in the topic i just linked to. But I got an error that read :

> make: *** No rule to make target 'makefile'.  Stop.

Comment: VS code isn't an IDE, but merely a code editor.

Comment: Check out this link to understand the difference between the two. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185139/difference-between-a-ide-and-text-editor

Comment: How is the makefile problem related to the editor?

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like it is coming from your makefile. (Assume you already installed [C/C++ support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools))

Check your makefile in the command line to make sure there is no mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`taskName` is passed as the first argument of the command. So if your command is "make" and your taskName is "makefile", the command line will be `make makefile`, leading to the error you are getting.

To avoid this behavior, add `"suppressTaskName": true,` inside the task declaration.